# Shell script to rename multiple files and folders

Tags: bash

I have the following structure

Before

```
-1.2.3.4
--1.2.3.4
---1.2.3.4-->1.2.3.4.file
```

After

```
-5.6.7.8
--5.6.7.8
---5.6.7.8-->5.6.7.8.file
...
```

I would like to use a bash script that searches files and subdirectories name in a specific directory /home for a specific string, and when it finds the search string (in file or
name, file content, subdirectories name), replaces the string (old1) with new string (new1), and so on old2 with new2 ....oldn with newn.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES_PATH="/home/pons/test"
FILES=$(find $FILES_PATH -type f -name "*")
for FILE in $FILES; do
    sed -i 's/old1/new1/ ; .... ; s/oldn/newn/' $FILE
done
```

e.g. replace fadi to server in all

```
[pons@server1 ~]$ pwd 
/home/pons 
[pons@server1 ~]$ cd test
[pons@server1 test]$ ls -al
total 12

drwxrwxr-x   3 pons pons 4096 Sep 29 09:50 .
drwx------. 26 pons pons 4096 Sep 29 10:21 ..
drwxrwxr-x   2 pons pons 4096 Sep 29 09:47 fadi
[pons@server1 test]$ cd fadi/ 
[pons@server1 fadi]$ pwd 
/home/pons/test/fadi
[pons@server1 fadi]$ ls -al
total 12<br/>
drwxrwxr-x 2 pons pons 4096 Sep 29 09:47 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 pons pons 4096 Sep 29 09:50 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pons pons   27 Sep 29 09:47 xxxfadixx.txt
[pons@server1 fadi]$ cat xxxfadixx.txt 
xxxxxxxxxxxxfadixxxxxxxxxx
[pons@server1 fadi]$
```

Can I add multiple string in one file and do the replace

e.g. create a file that specify filtering routines: 
    filter.txt 
    s/old1/new1/
    s/old2/new2/
    s/old3/new3/
    ......
    s/oldn/newn/

and then read that file in the script

```
#!/bin/bash

ROOT_DIR="$HOME/root"  # your target dir
P_FROM="1.2.3.4"
P_TO="5.6.7.8"

# for each directory, starting from deepest first
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' DIR_NAME; do
cd "$DIR_NAME"           # go to target dir
rename $P_FROM $P_TO *   # rename files
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec sed -i "s/$P_FROM/$P_TO/g" {} \;  
cd - > /dev/null         # back to original dir. Suppress stdout
done < <(find $ROOT_DIR -type d -depth -print0) # get only dirs
```

This above script from Shawn Chin worked perfectly replacing/renaming strings, how can I modify it if I have multiple string to be modified and these strings allocated in a file
 filter.txt 
    s/old1/new1/ 
    s/old2/new2/ 
    s/old3/new3/
 
    ......
    s/oldn/newn/

```
#!/bin/bash
ROOT_DIR="$HOME/test"  # your target dir
FILTER_FILE="$HOME/filter.sed"  # the sed script for renaming

# custom rename function that uses $FILTER_FILE (via sed)
function rename_using_filter {
CURRENT_NAME="$1"
NEW_NAME="$(echo $1 | sed -f $FILTER_FILE)"  # derive new name
if [ "$CURRENT_NAME" != "$NEW_NAME" ]; then  # rename if diff
    mv "$CURRENT_NAME" "$NEW_NAME"
fi
}

# for each directory, starting from deepest first
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' DIR_NAME; do
cd "$DIR_NAME"           # go to target dir

# for each file/dir at this level
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' FILE_NAME; do
    rename_using_filter "$FILE_NAME"  # rename it
    if [ -f "$FILE_NAME" ]; then                # if it's a file
        sed -i -f "$FILTER_FILE" "$FILE_NAME";  # replace content
    fi
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -print0)

cd - > /dev/null         # back to original dir. Suppress stdout
done < <(find $ROOT_DIR -depth -type d -print0) # get only dirs
```

I did the  above with filter.sed, it works replacing name files/directories but didnt replace the content of the file... can you check it please.

```
[pons@server1 test]$ find .
.
./boy_dir
./boy_dir/boy.txt
./papa
./papa/papa_new
./papa/papa_new/papa.txt
./boy
[pons@server1 test]$ cat ./papa/papa_new/papa.txt
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxpapaxxxxxxxxxxxx
[pons@server1 test]$ cat ./boy_dir/boy.txt
xxxxxxxxxxxxboyxxxxxxxxx
[pons@server1 test]$ cd ..
[pons@server1 ~]$ ./replace.sh 
[pons@server1 ~]$ cd test
[pons@server1 test]$ find .
.
./girl_dir
./girl_dir/girl.txt
./girl
./mama
./mama/mama_new
./mama/mama_new/mama.txt
[pons@server1 test]$ cat ./mama/mama_new/mama.txt
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxpapaxxxxxxxxxxxx
[pons@server1 test]$ cat ./girl_dir/girl.txt
xxxxxxxxxxxxboyxxxxxxxxx
[pons@server1 test]$ 


I used this filter 
[pons@server1 ~]$ cat filter.sed 
s/papa/mama/g;
s/boy/girl/g;
s/old3/new3/g;
s/old3/new4/g;
s/oldn/newn/g;




"filter.sed" 5L, 95C written                                                                                      
[pons@server1 ~]$ ./replace.sh 
[pons@server1 ~]$ cd test
[pons@server1 test]$ find .
.
./A.B.C.D.E_
./a.b.c.d.e
./a.b.c.d.e/a.b.c.d.e
./a.b.c.d.e_
./A.B.C.D.E
./A.B.C.D.E/A.B.C.D.E
[pons@server1 test]$ cat ./A.B.C.D.E/A.B.C.D.E
1.2.3.4.5
[pons@server1 test]$ cat ./a.b.c.d.e/a.b.c.d.e
6.7.8.9.0
[pons@server1 test]$ cat ./A.B.C.D.E_
1.2.3.4.5
[pons@server1 test]$ cat ./a.b.c.d.e_
6.7.8.9.0
[pons@server1 test]$ cd ..
[pons@server1 ~]$ ./replace.sh 
[pons@server1 ~]$ cd test
[pons@server1 test]$ find .
.
./A.B.C.D.E_
./a.b.c.d.e
./a.b.c.d.e/a.b.c.d.e
./a.b.c.d.e_
./A.B.C.D.E
./A.B.C.D.E/A.B.C.D.E
[pons@server1 test]$ cat ./A.B.C.D.E/A.B.C.D.E
A.B.C.D.E
[pons@server1 test]$ cat ./a.b.c.d.e/a.b.c.d.e
a.b.c.d.e
[pons@server1 test]$ cat ./A.B.C.D.E_
A.B.C.D.E
[pons@server1 test]$ cat ./a.b.c.d.e_
a.b.c.d.e
[pons@server1 test]$


[pons@server1 ~]$ vi filter.sed 

s/1.2.3.4.5/A.B.C.D.E/g;
s/6.7.8.9.0/a.b.c.d.e/g;
s/old3/new3/g;
s/old3/new4/g;
s/oldn/newn/g;
```

~

Comment: are you trying to replace the strings within a file or rename file files/dirs (or both?)? Your before/after structure indicates file/dir renaming, while you code replaces contents of files.

Comment: I want replace strings in files and files name beside that rename directories-names that include the string

Comment: Not a solution for exactly this problem. But I wrote mi (https://github.com/drizzd/mi) to make complicated renaming like this easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I gather, you want to traverse a directory structure and do the following:

1. Replace keywords/patterns within file or directory names.
2. Replace occurrences of the keywords/patterns within the content of files.

Here's how I would do it.

*Warning: long answer. If you're in a hurry, jump straight to the last section for complete script. Might also be over-engineer (there should be an easier way to do this, really...).*

Assuming the following file structure (based on your first example):

```
[me@home]$ find .
.
./1.2.3.4
./1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4
./1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4
./1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4.file
./1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4-2.file


[me@home]$ cat ./1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4.file
IP: 1.2.3.4

[me@home]$ cat ./1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4-2.file
IP: 1.2.3.4 (also)
```

#### Replacing patterns within files

This is the easy bit. One can do that quite simply using `find` and `sed`

```
[me@home]$ find . -type f -exec sed -i "s/1\.2\.3\.4/5.6.7.8/g" {} \;

[me@home]$ cat ./1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4.file
IP: 5.6.7.8

[me@home]$ cat ./1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4-2.file
IP: 5.6.7.8 (also)
```

#### Recursively renaming files/dirs

I first assumed it would be as simple as `find . -exec rename 1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8 {} \;`.

Unfortunately, that does not work. Prepending the command with an `echo` shows why it won't work.

```
[me@home]$ find . -exec echo rename 1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8 {} \;
rename 1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8 .
rename 1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8 ./1.2.3.4
rename 1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8 ./1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4
rename 1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8 ./1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4
rename 1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8 ./1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4.file
rename 1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8 ./1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4-2.file
```

The renaming of the top-level directory (`./1.2.3.4`) will succeed, but once we go down a level to rename `./1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4` this will fail because the parent directory has already been renamed.

We can reverse the order of traversal (using `-depth`) but that only solves half the problem since we need each step to rename only the lowest-level match and not the whole path.

What we therefore have to do is start the renaming process from the lowest level and work upwards. Here's one way to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

ROOT_DIR="$HOME/root"  # your target dir
P_FROM="1.2.3.4"
P_TO="5.6.7.8"

# for each directory, starting from deepest first
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' DIR_NAME; do
    (cd "$DIR_NAME" && rename $P_FROM $P_TO *)
done < <(find $ROOT_DIR -depth -type d -print0) # get only dirs
```

The complicated-looking `while` loop  allows us to handle filenames that contain spaces (see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020 for details).

This script assumes the [`rename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) command exists.

Running that script on our test directory gives the following results:

```
[me@home]$ bash renamer.sh

[me@home]$ find .
.
./5.6.7.8
./5.6.7.8/5.6.7.8
./5.6.7.8/5.6.7.8/5.6.7.8
./5.6.7.8/5.6.7.8/5.6.7.8/5.6.7.8.file
./5.6.7.8/5.6.7.8/5.6.7.8/5.6.7.8-2.file
```

#### Combining both steps into one script

We can combine both the steps above into one solution by simple adding the `find`+`sed` call into the loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

ROOT_DIR="$HOME/root"  # your target dir
P_FROM="1.2.3.4"
P_TO="5.6.7.8"

# for each directory, starting from deepest first
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' DIR_NAME; do
    cd "$DIR_NAME"           # go to target dir
    rename $P_FROM $P_TO *   # rename files
    find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec sed -i "s/$P_FROM/$P_TO/g" {} \;  
    cd - > /dev/null         # back to original dir. Suppress stdout
done < <(find $ROOT_DIR -depth -type d -print0) # get only dirs
```

### Update (renaming and rewriting files based on external sed file)

Assuming you have a sed file `filter.sed`:

```
s/old1/new1/g;
s/old2/new2/g;
s/old3/new3/g;
s/old3/new4/g;
s/oldn/newn/g;
```

Replacing contents of a file is simple as long as `filter.sed` is a valid sed file. We simply use the `-f` option:

```
[me@home]$ cat somefile.txt 
hello old1 old2 old3 world

[me@home]$ sed -i -f filter.sed somefile.txt 

[me@home]$ cat somefile.txt 
hello new1 new2 new3 world
```

However, renaming files/dirs however is trickier (unless you use the [Perl-based rename](http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-bulk-rename-files-in-linux-in-the-terminal) command available only on debian-based systems. With this you may be able to do something along the lines of `rename "$(cat filter.sed)" *`).

Using only the standard `mv` command, here's one way to do it. I suspect this may not the most efficient approach, but after briefly testing it, it *appears to* work. YMMV.

```
#!/bin/bash
ROOT_DIR="$HOME/root"  # your target dir
FILTER_FILE="$HOME/filter.sed"  # the sed script for renaming

# custom rename function that uses $FILTER_FILE (via sed)
function rename_using_filter {
    CURRENT_NAME="$1"
    NEW_NAME="$(echo $1 | sed -f $FILTER_FILE)"  # derive new name
    if [ "$CURRENT_NAME" != "$NEW_NAME" ]; then  # rename if diff
        mv "$CURRENT_NAME" "$NEW_NAME"
    fi
}

# for each directory, starting from deepest first
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' DIR_NAME; do
    cd "$DIR_NAME"           # go to target dir

    # for each file/dir at this level
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' FILE_NAME; do
        if [ -f "$FILE_NAME" ]; then                # if it's a file
            sed -i -f "$FILTER_FILE" "$FILE_NAME"   # replace content
        fi
        rename_using_filter "$FILE_NAME"  # rename it 
    done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -print0)

    cd - > /dev/null         # back to original dir. Suppress stdout
done < <(find $ROOT_DIR -depth -type d -print0) # get only dirs
```

Here's the script in action:

```
[me@home]$ find .
.
./old1_old2
./old1_old2/old3_old4
./old1_old2/old3_old4/some-oldn.txt
./renamr.sh

[me@home]$ cat old1_old2/old3_old4/some-oldn.txt 
hello old1 old2 old3 old4 oldn world

[me@home]$ bash renamr.sh

[me@home]$ find .
.
./.renamr.sh.swp
./new1_new2
./new1_new2/new3_new4
./new1_new2/new3_new4/some-newn.txt
./renamr.sh

[me@home]$ cat ./new1_new2/new3_new4/some-newn.txt
hello new1 new2 new3 new4 newn world
```

Comment: it works,  but I am getting this message [pons@server1 ~]$ ./replace.sh 
find: warning: you have specified the -depth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-depth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

Comment: @madunix That warning should go away if we use `-depth` as the first parameter (before `-type d`). Answer updated.

Comment: Ok .... the warning is gone .... can you look a above how can I add in the script to add multiple string integrated inside a file filter.txt

Comment: Is the multiple string matches for replacing file contents only? or filename/dirname as well? Also, is the format of `filter.txt` fixed?

Comment: yes absolute, same as above for all string  contents file name directories, the filter txt is fixed it will include all old string with new one as I stated above    old1 new1   old2  new2 .......  old3 new3........................................................... 
oldn newn    new line for each item and tabs between the old string and new one

Comment: @madunix OK. Updated answer to do roughly that. I didn't have much time to work on this, so I assumed your input `filter.txt` file is formatted as a valid sed script (see answer). It shouldn't be hard to parse your file into that format. Good luck.

Comment: I will check it tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: I checked today it works with the filter file, replacing string in the file names and directory names but it didn't replace the file content

Comment: I paste the result in the original post!

Comment: _@Shawn_ Can you help, see the above result only content I couldn't replace.

Comment: @madunix works find on my end. What happens when you run the `sed` command manually - `sed -i -f filter.sed ./mama/mama_new/mama.txt` ?

Comment: _@Shawn it works ... I checked it again ... but you need to run it twice, it should go in one step check above result

Comment: @madunix I see the problem. My fault. We have to do the replace before renaming the file. Script updated.

Comment: The answer was updated with the fix. Notice that the rename is now done after the replace.

Comment: How can I close this ticket, since my questions its been answered by @@Shawn?

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you can accept the answer by clicking on the tick (see FAQ link I provided).

Comment: I have tested the script lately... it works .... but found the the following string e.g  **10.6.20.15** been replaced with **A.B.C.D** that's correct  but the string **10.6.20.151** been replaced with wrong term instead to be **a.b.b.d**  its been replaced to **A.B.C.D1**  .. any comments

Comment: That's all down to how you write your filter.sed file. 10.6.20.151 contains 10.6.20.15 so if that rules come first, that replacement will take place. Try swapping the order or write more explicit regex patterns. I'm on the move for the next 2 weeks so I can't really help. If you start another question regarding the correct sed patterns to use, someone might be able to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You can run `rename` (yes, that's an existing program) for each replacement. For example, in Bash >=4.0, here's how to remove a ".bak" extension from all files within the current directory:

```
shopt -s globstar # Enable recursive globs with **
rename 's/\.bak$//' **.bak
```

Another example, to do several replacements:

```
$ touch /tmp/foobarbaz
$ rename 's/foo/bar/g;s/bar/baz/g' /tmp/foobarbaz
$ ls /tmp
bazbazbaz
```

For your specific replacements, this should work:

```
rename 's/old1/new1/ ; .... ; s/oldn/newn/' /home/pons/test/**
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that `rename` syntax is only available on debian-based distros. The standard `rename` is a lot less flexible: http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely understand what you want to achieve, but I think this will at least fix your code:

```
mv "$FILE" "$(echo "$FILE" | sed -i 's/old1/new1/ ; .... ; s/oldn/newn/')"
```

Comment: <br/> [pons@server1 fadi]$ pwd /home/pons/test/fadi<br/>  [pons@server1 fadi]$ ls -al <br/> total 12 drwxrwxr-x 2 pons pons 4096 Sep 29 09:47 . drwxrwxr-x 3 pons pons 4096 Sep 29 09:50 .. -rw-rw-r-- 1 pons pons 27 Sep 29 09:47 xxxfadixx.txt <br/> [pons@server1 fadi]$ [pons@server1 fadi]$ cat xxxfadixx.txt xxxxxxxxxxxxfadixxxxxxxxxx -->then i want to replace all string in failes name or contenet or directories sub above with other name from "fadi" to "server" <code>

Answer (score 0):

- Sed works on standard input or file content, not argument text or file names or anything like that.
- When reading output of find, do not store it all in variable, but read it line by line.

So you want to do something like:

```
find $FILES_PATH -type f | while read FILE; do
    NEWNAME="$(printf '%s\n' "$FILE" | sed 's/old1/new1/ ; .... ; s/oldn/newn/')"
    mv "$FILE" "$NEWNAME"
done
```

Note, that you do *not* want `-i` for sed, stdin can't be modified in place.

It can be more efficient by having sed output both names, so you can run it just once on the whole output, but with multiple substitutions that requires using the hold space. It goes like:

```
find $FILES_PATH -type f | sed 'h;s/old1/new1/;...;s/oldn/newn/;x;G' | while read OLD && read NEW; do
    mv "$OLD" "$NEW"
done
```

Comment: I keep getting this find: unknown predicate `-f'

Comment: That should be `-type f` (instead of `type -f`).

Comment: [pons@server1 fadi]$ pwd
/home/pons/test/fadi
[pons@server1 fadi]$ ls -al
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 pons pons 4096 Sep 29 09:47 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 pons pons 4096 Sep 29 09:50 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pons pons   27 Sep 29 09:47 xxxfadixx.txt
[pons@server1 fadi]$ [pons@server1 fadi]$ cat xxxfadixx.txt 
xxxxxxxxxxxxfadixxxxxxxxxx         -->then i want to replace all string in failes name or contenet or directories sub  above with other name  from "fadi"  to "server"

Comment: @madunix: I fixed the typo. Your other comment is not readable; edit the question instead, please.